Generating Functions $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}X^{F_n}$
Given the Fibonacci sequence $\left\{F_n\right\}\left(F_0=0, F_1=F_2=1, \ldots.\right)$. I'm wondering if there's a closed-form formula for the Generating Function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} X^{F_n}$. Are there any references that discuss this?
I came up with this question while working on generating functions for the Fibonacci sequence.

Usually the generating function there is $F(x) =\sum _{i=0}^{\infty}F_nx^n$, which is $F(x) = {1\over 1-x-x^2}$.

Considering that $F_n$ grow geometrically fast, the resulting series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{F_n}$ defines a lacunary function on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, which means that $f(x)$ does not arise from elementary functions.

An interesting explanation here invoking normal numbers for a similar series.
